# Highlight or outline any UIElement in adorner layer

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, adorner, uielement

I would like to be able to somehow outline or highlight any particular `UIElement` (or perhaps even `Visual`) in an adorner layer. Adorner is not a problem per se. I am more concerned about creating an outline of a `UIElement`.

I am aiming at a similar effect that `OuterGlowBitmapEffect` provides. I want to follow the outer contour of an `UIElement`. I have tried many approaches with examining `Clip` property (almost always null) and some other methods but I failed miserably.

Now I am thinking this must surely be easy it is just that I am missing something. In addition, Google was not my friend this time as well.

EDIT: NET 3.5 is a requirement

Comment: Can you provide a sample of how you want the highlighting to look? Have you tried `DropShadowEffect`?

Comment: See my comment to Aaron. I want to highlight the outline of the `Visual`. What I was thinking is getting a `Path` geometry of the outline and use that filled with a solid color and with animated opacity. The basis is somehow getting to the outline of *any* `Visual`. I haven't tried `DropShadowEffect`. I'd be more interested in a something that produces sort of *overlay* effect, not a shadow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `OpacityMask` with a `VisualBrush` with its `Visual` set to the element you want the outline of.  Here's an example where we have a `Rectangle` in the foreground and a `TabControl` in the background.  Since the tab control is not rectangular, we can see if the technique works:

```
<Grid Background="Gray">
    <TabControl Name="element">
        <TabItem Header="Tab1">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello, world!" FontSize="40" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Opacity="0.5">
        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=element}"/>
        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Visual Outline of a Control]

Only the tab control and its tab header are highlighted.

Comment: I have encountered the `OpacityMask` in conjunction with `ViusalBrush` before but I have never seen a full working example. Your screenshot seems to indicate this might actually do the trick for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to override the `OnRender` of the `UIElement` as seen in the [MSDN SimpleCircleAdorner example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746703.aspx).

```
  // A common way to implement an adorner's rendering behavior is to override the OnRender
  // method, which is called by the layout system as part of a rendering pass.
  protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
  {
    Rect adornedElementRect = new Rect(this.AdornedElement.DesiredSize);

    // Some arbitrary drawing implements.
    SolidColorBrush renderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    renderBrush.Opacity = 0.2;
    Pen renderPen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Navy), 1.5);
    double renderRadius = 5.0;

    // Draw a circle at each corner.
    drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, adornedElementRect.TopLeft, renderRadius, renderRadius);
    drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, adornedElementRect.TopRight, renderRadius, renderRadius);
    drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, adornedElementRect.BottomLeft, renderRadius, renderRadius);
    drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, adornedElementRect.BottomRight, renderRadius, renderRadius);
  }
}
```

If you want to provide a robust solution outside a typical rectangle or rounded rectangle you will have to make use of [path geometries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751808.aspx) which will allow you to build out a path composed of segments such as a `BezierSegment`, a `LineSegment`, or an `ArcSegment` thus creating an appropriate path around the `UIElement`.

If on the other hand a rectangle or rounded rectangle would suffice you can make use of the `DrawingContext.DrawRectangle` and `DrawingContext.DrawRoundedRectangle` respectively within the `OnRender` override.

Comment: +1, Thanks so much for the proposed solution. Unfortunately, what I am looking for is following the outline of the `UIElement` (or `Visual`) not just simple (rounded) rectangles. I was thinking of getting the path you are talking about, but in a programmatic manner. I want this approach to work on *any* UIElement, not some set of predefined shapes.